# VB.NET 2010 Post-KeyPress Event

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

..This is a reworking of a previously deleted question, I'm rewording to try to be more clear..

VB.NET 2010 Winform with a Datagridview.
User is able to type into an editable cell.
As they type, the "current" value of the cell should be used to search through an array of radiobuttons and select the button that matches the typed value.

Issue is that the user could type a value, but then type a DEL or BACKSPACE to alter the value.  And the DEL/BACKSPACE of course doesn't have to be done at end of value, could be anywhere.  Also a cells value isn't "finalized" until after this event is complete.

My original code looked like this...

```
Private Sub txtdgvDiaryEdit_Keypress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs)
    'Test for numeric value or backspace 
    If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar.ToString()) _
    Or e.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
        e.Handled = False 'if numeric  
        '******************************************************

        If IsNumeric(e.KeyChar.ToString()) Then
            If DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text.Length = 0 Then
                Call SelectRadioButtonForValue(e.KeyChar.ToString)
            Else
                Dim strvar As String
                strvar = DirectCast(sender, TextBox).Text.ToString + e.KeyChar.ToString
                Call SelectRadioButtonForValue(strvar.ToString)
            End If
        Else ...
```

But this doesn't pick up the value of the cell AFTER the DEL/BACKSPACE.
AND I can't use any kind of CELL VALUE CHANGES Because those don't fire till i'm actually LEAVING the cell.

I need to be able to pick up the actual cell value AFTER the Keypress had been processed but remain in EDIT MODE.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you binding to the events of the [DataGridView.EditingControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?  If not, consider doing so.  Also see [DataGridView.EditingControlShowing Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information on using the editing control.

Comment: @TnTinMn Yes.  My KEYPRESS was done so.  However like I said, the cell value was NOT available.  I just added a Handler for KEYUP and it apparently will do what I want.  Will be testing.

Comment: Access the value from the editing control directly.